# Will .NET Framework 4 desktop application [C#] run Windows 8, 8.1 and 10

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am very new to .NET and have limited knowledge about .NET. Currently  learning and using C# in visual studio 2010. 
I build a small desktop application with .NET 4 and C# in Windows 7 X64.

So now i have query, will my application run on windows 8, 8.1 and 10 ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why on earth use a six year old IDE?  Is this some stupid requirement by an employer or teacher?  Oh, and the answer is yes.

Comment: If they have .Net 4.0 installed, then yes (hint: they probably do).

Comment: @Will Visual Studio costs money, and not all companies are eager to pay for it as soon as new version comes out. I know a few companies that use VS2010 and plan to move on to the next studio _**after**_ 2015.

Comment: @Will Actually I am a Student. and at present time I cant afford to buy VS 2015. That is why using VS 2010.

Comment: You don't have to buy anything.  The community edition is FREE https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x409&downloadrename=true if you have an .edu email address, you can get the enterprise edition FOR FREE.  https://www.dreamspark.com/  But keep on using a six year old IDE if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8, 8.1 and Windows 10 has the .Net version that will support .Net framework 4.0 applications. For example with Windows 8.0, .Net Framework 4.5 is installed by default. .Net framework supports [backward compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx) so any 
application developed in Version 4.5 or earlier will work on Windows 8.

See: [What version of the .NET Framework is included in what version of the OS?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/)

> Windows 8 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 4.5 as an OS
>   component, and it is installed by default.

and

> Windows 10 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 4.6 as an OS
>   component, and it is installed by default.

Comment: Great help. Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your application will run on any operating system supporting the .NET version you've choosen.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your application will run on any Operating System. The thing is to check that the machine you are trying to run the application should have .Net Framework version installed.